# Fastest & Safest method to paginate a ready AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pagination

```js
function ajaxFetch () {
  var search = $('input').val();
  $.get('fetch.php', {search: search}, function(data){
      $('div').html(data);
  })
  
}
$('input').keyup(function(){
  ajaxFetch();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search'>
<div></div>
```

in my Script here i fetch data from a table coming from `fetch.php`

```
<?php 
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    if(isset($_GET['offset'])){ $offset = $_GET['offset';] } else { $offset = 0 }
    $limit = 5;
    $sql = "
    SELECT a.name, b.fname, c.lname, d.mname FROM table a
    LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.id = b.id 
    LEFT JOIN tablec c ON a.id = c.id 
    LEFT JOIN tabled d ON a.id = d.id 
    WHERE a.name LIKE %$search% AND a.vara = :vara AND a.varb = :varb AND a.varc = :varc
    LIMIT $offset, $limit
    ";
    ~..prepare()..execute()..~
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<span>{$row['name']},{$row['fname']}, {$row['lname']}, {$row['mname']}</span>";
    }

    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $total = $stmt->rowCount();
    $offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;
    $start = $offset + 1;
    $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);
    if ($total > 5) {
        $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=1" title="First page">&laquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';
        $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';
    }
?>
```

I've tried using my way using `rowCount()` at the same query to save time and SQL processes, But it didn't work, So i wonder what is the best and quickest and safest way to make this Pagination work?

Or do i just go with the traditiona 2 queries one of them is `COUNT(*)` then `onclick` on pagination link call `ajaxFetch()` again with a new offset?

Comment: You sure the query works?  `table-b`  would generate a SQL error because you can't use dash (-) as table or column name without using backtickes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Oh, It wasn't actually in the main code at all, the `-`. sorry about that.

Comment: You can use `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.name, b.fname, c.lname, d.mname ....` and `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` to succesfully replace `$total = $stmt->rowCount();` read ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows )

Comment: @RaymondNijland that would be a two query method, Since i need to retrieve data too.

Comment: @RaymondNijland is using `FOUND_ROWS()` is faster than `COUNT(*)` method?

Comment: i saw some benchmarks between `FOUND_ROWS()` and `COUNT(*)`.. the performance depends on using indexes and stuff like that.. most off the time `COUNT(*)` with correct indexes beats the `FOUND_ROWS()` method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the query used to generate the output contains a `LIMIT` clause and will thus never return the number of **all** possible rows, you have to perform your query twice.

Comment: Can it be handled using `JSON` or is the **only** || **fastet** way is two queries?

Comment: Use two queries. JSON is just the format of messages between your browser and your webserver